# How to resolve version conflicts preventing npm package installation in Angular 16 application?

Tags: angular, package.json, angular16

I'm currently working on an Angular 16 application, and I'm encountering issues when trying to install npm packages. It appears that there is a version conflict among the dependencies specified in my package.json file. Here's a snippet of my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "mail-generator",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~15.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "~15.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-richtexteditor": "^22.2.10-ngcc",
    "@types/quill": "^1.3.10",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^17.0.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "quill-blot-formatter": "^1.0.5",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have specified the Angular dependencies with a version of ^16.2.0. However, when I try to install npm packages, I'm getting version conflicts.

What steps can I take to resolve these version conflicts and successfully install the required npm packages for my Angular 16 application? Should I update my Angular dependencies, or is there another approach to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of npm install , use

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

It ignores all the peerDependencies when installing.